# How can I access my parent class property without initializing it in the parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am learning java for the last one week, sorry for the dumb question but if i just declare a variable in the parent class without storing any value in it, maybe use a setter or constructor for inputing its value then can I work with those values/properties of the parent class in a child class?

```
class circle2 
{
    double radius;
    double Area;
    Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    void SetRadius() {
        System.out.println("Enter Radius");
        radius = Sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
class cylinder2 extends circle2
    {
    double height=5,volume;
    void GetVolume(){

        volume=Math.PI*radius*radius*height;
        System.out.println("Volume of cylinder : " + volume);
    }
}

public class Ch10Alternate_PS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        circle2 obj = new circle2();
        obj.SetRadius();
        cylinder2 obj1 = new cylinder2();
        obj1.GetVolume();
  }
}
```

This gives me a value of 0.0 for volume

Comment: doubles are initialized as 0.0 when you don't assign a value yourself

Comment: And your `volume` only exists in the **child** (not the **parent**) class.

Comment: I edited it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Unrelated. learn about java naming conventions. Class always start UpperCase. And method names go camelCase. And hint: a method that is named getX should **return** a value. PRINTING to the console is a side effect. Dont do it like that. Or call the method printX() when you really want to do it that way.

Comment: @AngsuSen You are creating 2 objects and setting the radius in one getting the volume of another. You need to do `SetRadius()` on `obj1`. Your `circle2 obj` object is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding inheritance here. Both the variables `obj` and `obj1` have a different `radius` property. When you create an instance of `cylinder2` it has an underlying `circle2` - think of it like creating a specialised version of `circle2`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys @OHGODSPIDERS  i got it now, i don't know how to choose answers or anything. so should i just delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two objects, a circle and a cylinder. You are setting the radius of the circle. Then you are calculating the volume of the cylinder. Which result do you expect?

The solution is to set the radius of the cylinder:

```
    cylinder2 obj1 = new cylinder2();
    obj1.SetRadius();
    obj1.GetVolume();
```

Sample session:

```
Enter Radius
3
Volume of cylinder : 141.3716694115407
```

The problem really had not got anything to do with what was in the parent class and what was in the child class. It all ends up in the same object when you create one.